# Install custom tool using VSIX without running devenv /setup

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsix

I have created a custom tool within a Visual Studio 2012 "Package" project and am distributing it via a .vsix file.  Everything works great but the custom tool is not registered unless I run "devenv.exe /setup".  Is there any way around this?  I was under the impression ([and it seems to be confirmed by the EF team](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/804)) that this only needed to be done when installing using an MSI.